# Update Manager not working and Software center crashes

Tags: updates, software-center

on running the Update Manager, following message shows up

```
E: Encountered a section with no package
E: Problem with MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/oem.archive.canonical.com_updates_dists_precise-oem-sp1_public_i18n_Translation-en
The package list could not be opened or parsed.
Installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Software center also crashes as soon as it starts.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands one by one:

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
 sudo aptitude update
 sudo aptitude upgrade
```

If that doesn't fix your problem use the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/oem.archive.canonical.com_updates_dists_precise-oem-sp1_public_i18n_Translation-en
sudo apt-get update
```

for dependencies issues

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```